# wagtail hallojs editor video embed with padding-bottom

Tags: css, django, responsive-design, video-embedding, wagtail

I was playing around with [wagtail](http://wagtail.io/) and had a strange `padding-bottom` issue when inserting a video using the default wagtail editor ([hallojs](http://hallojs.org/)). Turns out the video is wrapped in a `.responsive-object` div with inline style `padding-bottom: 62.5%;`. Since my video wasn't responsive at all, I gess there was something I did't do correctly.

[image: vimeo embed not responsive]

I had a huge padding under the embedded video. I couldn't find a place explaining how to integrate wagtail's editor generated html. There's [a page in the documentation](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/editor_manual/new_pages/inserting_videos.html) about video embedding, but nothing useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Solution

It was easy, searched for `.responsive-object` and found [embed.ly responsive tutorial](http://embed.ly/docs/tutorials/responsive). To make everything look good again, I needed this css:

```
.responsive-object {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 67.5%;
  height: 0;
  margin: 10px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.responsive-object iframe,
  .responsive-object object,
  .responsive-object embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

### Result

[image: vimeo embed now resposnive (yay!)]

If someone finds something on how to integrate content properly from the hallojs editor, leave a comment or an answer ;)

Comment: FYI, this class is covered in the "Building your Site (for frontend developers)" doc here: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/building_your_site/frontenddevelopers.html#responsive-embeds

Comment: Thanks, I just realized I skipped the `Template tags & filters` while reading `Building your site` in the docs.

Comment: Just my little update, I was looking for solution for draftail in newest Wagtail 2.5.1 and these css classes work perfectly. My youtube video is responsive, thank you.